# map.fitBounds() don't work on my Dynamic Path (Polyline)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm really going crazy trying to figure out why my map fails to resize automatically when they get the points that come out of the map.
Can anyone figure out what am I doing wrong?
there is some way to force the map to be updated?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&sensor=TRUE">
    </script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var poly = new MVCArray();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878058, 12.554911),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

 var polyOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  };
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
  poly.setMap(map);
};

function addLatLng(x, y) {
  var currLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
  var path = poly.getPath();

  path.push(currLatlng);
  map.setMarker(new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat:x,lng:y},map:map}));

  bounds.extend(currLatlng);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
</script>
<script>
   io = io.connect()

// Emit ready event.
    io.emit('ready')
    io.on('talk', function(data) {
                addLatLng(data.lat, data.long);
     });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **that demonstrates the issue**.

Comment: From glancing at it, your code appears correct. You should learn to use your console to debug. It's much faster than asking SO questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have several errors.
To begin `google.maps.Map.setMarker` is not a Google Maps API V3 function.

You cannot initialize `poly` as a `new MVCArray` because `MVCArray` is not definded, besides you don't need to do that.

Check out this code, to work with it you only need to click the map for add a marker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map Fit Polyline</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 500px;
            min-height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label id="display-zoom-label">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var poly;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878058, 12.554911),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (elem) {
                var latLng = elem.latLng;
                addLatLng(latLng.lat(), latLng.lng());
            });

            var polyOptions = {
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 3
            };
            poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
            poly.setMap(map);
        };

        function addLatLng(x, y) {
            var currLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            var path = poly.getPath();

            path.push(currLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: { lat: x, lng: y }, map: map });

            bounds.extend(currLatlng);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```